# Creating an anonymous object via LINQ from IObservable?

Tags: c#, json, linq, system.reactive

I've inherited a byzantine API that accesses remote data via JSON, the queries themselves are dealt with via TPL which for reasons I won't go into is backing me into a corner.

So, I have an IObservable subscription, which I query as thus;

```
mcSub.Take(1).Subscribe(x => x.Markets.ForEach(i => i.Prices.AvailableToBuy.ForEach(t => tabPanel.textBox1.AppendText(i.Id + " Back \t" + t.Size + " @ " + t.Price))));
```

Obviously Markets and AvailableToBuy are lists, my question is - how can I create a LINQ query/object to extract i.Id, t.Size and t.Price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this, by flattening twice (once the markets, and then the prices) in one collection with all prices:

```
//get all prices available to buy:
var pricesAvailableToBuy = mcSub.SelectMany(x => x.Markets)
                           .SelectMany(y => y.Prices.AvailableToBuy)
                           .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Size, p.Price });
```

This gives you all prices for all markets in `mcSub`, while your initial statement works only on one market item (which also depends how it's called - if it's on a consumer worker task/thread then it makes sense).

Or, a similar formulation:

```
var pricesAvailableToBuy = mcSub.SelectMany(x => x.Markets.SelectMany(y => y.Prices.AvailableToBuy))
                           .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Size, p.Price });
```

Answer (score 1):

Woof.

That is one nasty honking subscribe/query blob. Let's see if we can clean that up somewhat...I see you're taking 1 from mcSub and subscribing to it, so I'll assume it's an enumerable of observables?

Let's first fake up some types I can refer to (I'll do my best to infer from your sample):

First, the data items:

```
public class Thing 
{
    public List<Market> Markets {get; set;}
}
public class Market
{
    public Price Prices {get; set;}
}
public class Price
{
    public List<AvailablePrice> AvailableToBuy {get; set;}  
}
public class AvailablePrice
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

Next, the thing that will generate an `IEnumerable<IObservable<Thing>>`, which I will ham-handedly hack together:

```
public IEnumerable<IObservable<Thing>> GetThingsObs()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => {
        return Observable.Create<Thing>(obs =>
        {
            var things = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new Thing() 
            { 
                Markets = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select<int, Market>(x => 
                {                   
                    return new Market()
                    {
                        Prices = new Price
                        {
                            AvailableToBuy = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
                                .Select(y => new AvailablePrice { Id = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", i, x, y), Size = rnd.Next(0, 10), Price = rnd.Next(0, 20) })
                                .ToList()
                        }
                    };
                }).ToList()
            });
            foreach(var thing in things)
                obs.OnNext(thing);

            // this bit is important, but I'll get back to it later
            obs.OnCompleted();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    });
}
```

Ok, now that we've got something that'll (I hope) map somewhat to your data, let's query!

IF the observable is known to complete (the bit above I glossed over), you can transform an `IObservable<T>` into an `IEnumerable<T>` reasonably safely - If it does *not* complete, this will basically hang, so be careful!

```
var mcSub = GetThingsObs();
var query = 
    // for each observable
    from obs in mcSub   

    // this replaces your subscribe calls, but the observable MUST complete
    // for this to return properly!         
    from thing in obs.ToEnumerable()

    // After that, it's just multiple SelectManys 
    // (which is what the nested 'from x in y' calls get translated into)

    // For each market
    from market in thing.Markets
    // for each price thingy
    from price in market.Prices.AvailableToBuy
    // select out your stuff
    select new { price.Id, price.Size, price.Price };
```

That's the best guess I can make from the sample you've provided - if you can provide any more information/details, I'll take another shot at it if this doesn't work for ya.

Comment: It's a very, enumerable way of doing things.